# How do you mute the local mic using Agora's Web SDK v4.x & trigger the mute-audio event

Tags: agora.io

I am using Agora's Web SDK for group audio calls. I'm trying to implement a simple mute button that a user can click once they are in the call to mute their audio.

When a local user mutes their mic, remote users should see that user's mic is muted. To accomplish this, when a user connects to a stream, we add an event handler to listen for the "mute-audio" event that should fire when a remote user mutes their mic.

In the Web SDK 3.x series there is a stream object with a mute function, but in the 4.x Agora API, I don't see such a function.

Right now I am using localAudioTrack.setVolume(0) to mute and localAudioTrack.setVolume(100) to unmute, which works except it does not fire the "mute-audio" event to let remote participants know that a remote user is muted or unmuted.

I've also tried localAudioTrack.setEnabled(false) to mute the local audio, but that doesn't work.

Would appreciate some guidance here. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

`setEnabled` is the right way to mute audio/video in the new Agora NG SDK.

**Sample Code:**

```js
function toggleMic() {
  if ($("#mic-icon").hasClass('fa-microphone')) {
    localTracks.audioTrack.setEnabled(false);
    console.log("Audio Muted.");
  } else {
    localTracks.audioTrack.setEnabled(true);
    console.log("Audio Unmuted.");
  }
  $("#mic-icon").toggleClass('fa-microphone').toggleClass('fa-microphone-slash');
}

// Toggle Video
function toggleVideo() {
  if ($("#video-icon").hasClass('fa-video')) {
    localTracks.videoTrack.setEnabled(false);
    console.log("Video Muted.");
  } else {
    localTracks.videoTrack.setEnabled(true);
    console.log("Video Unmuted.");
  }
  $("#video-icon").toggleClass('fa-video').toggleClass('fa-video-slash');
}
```

- [Sample App](https://github.com/akshatvg/Agora-Many-to-Many-Live-Streaming-SDK-NG)
- [NG SDK Docs](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/api/en/index.html)

Comment: Thank you! When I use `setEnabled` I don't see the `client.on("unmute-audio", (evt) => {...})`  callback triggered for remote clients.

Comment: it will trigger "user-unpublished" event instead. There is no "unmute-audio" event in SDK v4.x